# cufon or typeface - need English LTR and Arabic RTL fancy heading

Tags: drupal, cufon, right-to-left, typeface.js

I need to build a site that uses cufon or typeface.js for headings.  But I am struggling to get a definitive answer on whether these will support RTL text.

Does anyone have experience using these for arabic / RTL text? And if they aren't suitable, can you recommend an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to use cufon for 'Persian'.As you may notice , It was told that -on github project page- the developers have plan to make support for rtl either.
It's really awsome solution but still got some problem.